# Java 19 Using ClassLoader.getResource() returns null

Tags: java

Try

```java
@FXML
private ImageView img;
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
try{
    img.setImage(new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("icons/a.png").toURI().toString()));
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

on Java 19 will return error that `Cannot invoke java.net.URL.toURI() because the return value of java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String) is null`

Whereas on Java 13 it works as intended.

Comment: This is quite unclear. Please update question with some detailed information. Are you sure that png exists under the project on the given path? How did you try it? On command line or in an IDE? If you tried it in an IDE, are you sure the project settings are correct? I would bet it's not a classloading issue neither Java 19 issue.

Comment: @zforgo the PNG does exist as `resources/icons/a.png`. As I stated above, the code works perfectly in Java 13. I'm trying this on NetBeans 16, and project is loaded using default settings, except Javafx-version (19 vs 13) and javafx-maven-plugin-version (0.0.8 vs 0.0.4) respectively.

Comment: i'm running into the same issue with amazon-corretto-17.jdk even though class path is accurate: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toURI()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null`

Comment: @PhiAgent the only workaround I've found thus far is to use `getClass().getResource("icons/a.png").toString()));` and create directories as `/src/main/resources/com/example/icons/a.png` where `com` and `example` are your GroupId and ProjectName, respectively.

Comment: @JavaUser007, i figured out what the problem was: my file path was setup incorrectly